# Find questions with missing domain tags

Tags: discussion, tags, data-explorer

I think it is important that every question has at least one **domain tag**. These tags make it possible that experts find relevant questions to answer (and searchers find relevant solutions), while **secondary tags** allow to narrow down.

Examples for domain tags:
[software-development](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development), [text-editors](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-editors), [image-processing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing), [cms](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cms), [document-converter](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/document-converter), [download-manager](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/download-manager), [ocr](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ocr)

Examples for secondary tags:
[gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis), [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows), [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps), [library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library), [javascript](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline)

Examples for tags that could be domain tags in some cases, but are often only secondary tags (e.g., because they only specify the formats that need to be supported):
[pdf](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf), [html](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html), [csv](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csv), etc.; and to some extent [video](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video), [images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images), etc.

**Is it possible to create a Data Explorer query that finds our questions which are tagged *only* with secondary tags?**

(If we can use such a query, and the below list is deemed useful for that purpose, I’ll move it to a separate Meta discussion where it can be curated.)

### Incomplete list of secondary tags

**How the software must be distributed**:

- [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis)
- [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source)

**On which platform¹ the software must run:**

- [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android)
- [blackberry](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackberry)
- [chrome-os](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome-os)
- [firefox-os](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox-os)
- [ios](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) ([ipad-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad-app), [iphone-app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone-app))
- [linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) ([centos-7](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centos-7), [debian](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian), [ubuntu](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu))
- [osx](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx)
- [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) ([windows-7](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-7), [windows-8](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-8), [windows-10](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-10), [windows-xp](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp))
- [windows-ce](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-ce)
- [windows-phone](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone)
- [windows-rt](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-rt)
- [windows-server](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-server)
- ~ [cross-platform](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-platform)

**Of what nature the software must be:**

- [cli](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cli)
- [command-line](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line)
- [desktop-client](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-client)
- [framework](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framework)
- [library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library)
- [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps) ([hosted](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosted), [self-hosted](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-hosted))
- [widget](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/widget)

**In which programming language the software must be written in:**

- [java](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java), [javascript](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and many more

**What technical requirements the software must fulfill:**

- [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline)
- [gui](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui)
- [portable](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portable)
- [multi-user](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-user)

---

¹ Tags for a specific software/service ([chrome](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome), [eclipse](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse), [google-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps), [skype](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skype), [amazon](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon), etc.) are similar to platform tags. Questions with these tags should ideally also have a domain tag, but the issue is not as big as with platforms tags, because we get less questions, and the domain is often narrow enough.

Answer (score 3):

That's a great analysis and well thought-through (upvoted it already). And while we cannot make any combination "mandatory"<sup>**1**</sup>, neither could we expect all (especially new) users to "fully comply" – this would still be useful for reviewers to improve quality. I'm not familiar enough with data-explorer to provide such a query, but I like (and support) the idea.

So, if this is possible, I'd say we should do it. Regardless how frequently it will be used in-depth: everything improving quality should be welcome. And this wouldn't just improve quality, but also make searches easier.

---

<sup>**1:** there will always be exceptions where something "doesn't work out" or is "unclear to chose" – e.g. software needed for either Linux or Android must not necessarily be cross-platform, and it's doubtful if both tags should be used then, especially given the limit of 5 tags; artificial case: "Linux or Android or Windows video-converter open-source and free" would already make 6 tags ;)</sup>